# print a colum number of times the value of other column in perl

Tags: bash, perl

I have a similar requirement as seen in [How to repeat values from a specific column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56743148/how-to-repeat-values-from-a-specific-column)

I already know the solution from the aforementioned question and this answer(https://stackoverflow.com/a/56743282/6309601). but for sake of learning `perl`, I am trying to do it with `perl`. No other reason.

```
echo "$y"
5 aws
2 openstack
1 azure
3 others
```

I am able to print the data, but I am not able to understand why white spaces are appearing in the output .

```
echo "$y" |perl -lanE 'say "$F[1]\n" x "$F[0]"'
aws
aws
aws
aws
aws

openstack
openstack

azure

others
others
others
```

Can someone please help me with , explaining why extra white spaces are added ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The newline after `$F[1]` is causing the additional line between groups. You can avoid this by changing your code slightly to use repetition in list context + join:

```
echo '5 aws
2 openstack
1 azure
3 others' | perl -lanE 'say join "\n", ($F[1]) x $F[0]'
# aws
# aws
# aws
# aws
# aws
# openstack
# openstack
# azure
# others
# others
# others
```

Things of note:

- the [`x`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Multiplicative-Operators) operator in list context (caused by the parentheses around
  `$F[1]`) returns a list of the elements repeated. e.g. ('aws') x 3
  will return 'aws', 'aws', 'aws'
- [`join`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/join.html) accepts a delimiter and a list
  to combine

There are likely many ways to do this, this is just one that came to mind easily for me.

Comment: Or, `perl -lape '$_ = "$F[1]\n" x "$F[0]"; chomp'` or `perl -lane 'print $F[1] for 1..$F[0]'`